# is it possible to share applications installed on a windows or linux server with the client machine in the same LAN

Tags: networking

is it possible to share applications installed on a windows or linux server with the client machine in the same LAN? for example, the ms word application installed on windows server and i want to use this application on the other computer which is connected with the server in the same LAN.

Comment: as far as linux goes most of the products are free so just install the app on the client PC.  Is there a reason not to just install it on the client linux PC local from a repo?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a license for just one copy of MS Word, you cannot legally use it in more than one computer at the same time.

But technically? It depends on the application. Back in 1999 or so, I think it was possible to make a special network installation of MS Office to a network share (when appropriately licensed for such use), then have that share mapped to several client machines. But I think it was still necessary to run a kind of a mini-installation process on each client to have all the features work correctly.

(Sure, you could have just opened the network share and double-clicked `word.exe`. But if you wanted to e.g. double-click a `.doc` file and have it open in Word, the operating system would need to know where to find that `word.exe` to open it. And that is one of the things the installer would set up.)

Today, disk capacity is considered so cheap that network installations like that are very rare.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server can publish applications to be used over LAN.
This needs to be a real Windows Server version and not just any Windows 10 computer.

For more information, see documentation for the RemoteApps feature:

- [Publishing RemoteApps in Windows Server 2012](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10817.publishing-remoteapps-in-windows-server-2012.aspx)
- [Step by Step How to Deploy RemoteApp in Windows Server 2016](https://newhelptech.wordpress.com/2017/07/23/step-by-step-how-to-deploy-remote-desktop-services-in-windows-server-2016/)